# How to get Excel cells range font color using EPPlus 4.1 and LookupColor method?

Tags: powershell, epplus, epplus-4

It appears `LookupColor()` always returns black (`"FF000000"`) not the actual font color when called like this:

```
var color = worksheet.Cells[1,1,1,5].Style.Font.Color.LookupColor();
```

It could be a bug, but I would love to hear if someone is using this reliably or if there is better syntax/way to get the font/foreground color?

*On another note I had real trouble executing the above statement in PowerShell as I always got the error:* `Cannot find an overload for "LookUpColor" and the argument count: "0".` *However it turned out the error is only with the .Net 4 binaries - I got it to work with the .Net 3.5 binaries, but the value is not accurate (I have PowerShell v5 installed)...*

UPDATE:
Another call I tried by passing and argument to the method also does not produce the expected result:

```
var color = worksheet.Cells[1,1,1,5].Style.Font.Color
    .LookupColor(worksheet.Cells[1,1,1,5].Style.Font.Color);
```

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but just in case you're not aware of 'ImportExcel' (a PS module that uses EPPlus), here's the link: https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel

Comment: Doug, I appreciate your comment and I think your work is awesome, just downloaded your module! Correct me if I am wrong - I do not see a way to generate additional data column based on the font color of current excel row being imported. This is my requirement... Any pointers greatly appreciated - Thanks!

Comment: Hey Emil. I'm just a user of the module. You can reach out to Doug on Twitter @dfinke. He may appear here though as I've tweeted him about this.

Comment: Thanks Robin - I should read the poster's name next time :) For some reason I assumed it was Doug. Thanks for your input anyway!

Comment: Meanwhile I logged this [LookupColor issue](https://epplus.codeplex.com/workitem/15533) (if problem for you you can vote it up) on the [EPPlus project issue tracking list](https://epplus.codeplex.com/workitem/list/basic)